# How do I create a dropdown list from a range that will update if the range is updated?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to have a dropdown validation that has a list from a range that updates the chosen value if the source range is updated. Is that possible in Google Sheets?

Let's say I have this range in one sheet:

```
Approved
Rejected
In Progress
```

In another sheet, I select a data validation of "list from a range" that pulls in the range above. No problem there.

But if I change the value in the source--let's say from "In Progress" to "Underway"--I would also want the values in that drop down validation to change as well. Instead, they only pull in the value when the dropdown is first selected, and it has to be manually updated if the source data is updated.

Comment: Piece of cake, share your sheet and I will show you

Comment: I put together this sample sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y0AuJjISztXrsJo1rlCa2RKPUS3vGwH-ITqpD3vLWoc/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you!

Comment: Hmm, not such a piece of cake after all. Let me ponder some more unless somebody else has a solution. Custom formula is out as the dropdown goes away.

Comment: Does updating your Data Validation's Criteria to "List from a range" with ='Dropdown values'!$A$2:$A$4 on your "Menu Table" sheet auto-updates the drop down validation values?

Comment: I need to have the dropdown on that part of the menu, so I can't change it to a custom formula. The value of the "List from a range" is ='Dropdown values'!$A$2:$A$4